# PHP template and bootstrap font awesome

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, dreamweaver, font-awesome

i been work on php Template (.dwt.php) and in the header i put fontawsome css
but the font awesome not work whatever i do i try change fonts paths and its not work here code of the php template

```
<?php 
require "header.php";
if(!$_SESSION['UserAssoc']['Administrator']) Redirect("home.php", "Insufficient Privileges");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
<title>NOMS</title>
<!-- TemplateEndEditable --><!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="head" --><!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<link href="css/thin-admin.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/smooth-sliding-menu.js"></script> 
</head>
```

and here my fontawsome.css file

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.2.1');
    src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.2.1') format('embedded-opentype'), 
    url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1') format('woff'), 
    url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.2.1') format('truetype'), 
    url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular?v=3.2.1') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

and i have all this fonts in folder called fonts and the fontawsome.css in the css folder can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to load FontAwesome like that; you can just use the stylesheet.  Don't need to use fontface:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: After you add the stylesheet to your <head>, you can use <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> to test it out.